# 404 Not Found Flask

Tags: flask

I'm building an application that has the structure outlined below. At this point, it's a very simple application. However, I can't figure out how to render index.html. I'm not sure what I'm missing:

```
/application
--config.py
--setup.py
--__init__.py
--/app
----/__init__.py
--/controllers
----/test.py
----/__init__.py
--/views
----/static
----/templates
------/index.html
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from application import config

class App(Flask):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__(__name__)
        self.config.from_object('application.config')
```

**controllers/test.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask.views import MethodView
from application.app import App
from application import config

test = Blueprint(
    'test',
    __name__,
    template_folder=config.TEMPLATES,
)

class Index(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        ...
        return render_template('index.html', error=error)

test.add_url_rule("/", view_func=Index.as_view('index'))
```

**setup.py**

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Command
from application import config
from application.app import App

app = App()
manager = Manager(app)

class InitApplication(Command):

    def execute(self):
        ...

manager.add_command('init', Init())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

**config.py**

```
import os

TEMPLATES = "{}/application/views/templates/".format(os.getcwd())
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blueprints need to be [registered](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#registering-blueprints) against a Flask object.

```
from flask import Flask
from application import config

class App(Flask):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__(__name__)
        self.config.from_object('application.config')

        from application.controllers.test import test
        self.register_blueprint(test)
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.